# Is "key" a reserved word in MySqli? I'm getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just getting into MySql/MySqli really, and I'm using prepared statements.
The whole of my script is working fine except this single line:

`if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT bandHash, userHash, userPassHash, type FROM account_active WHERE key=?")) {`

I found out that's the line by manually tracking it down, then running the `mysqli_error($resource)` function, and got this result `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key=?' at line 1`

Please don't worry that it says line 1, that's just because of how it's been executed, it's actually line 280.

So what I'm wondering, because I'm already using statements like this, is "key" a reserved word that I cannot use - or do I need to look elsewhere for my error?

A simple yes or no answer will suffice, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's because it's line 1 of the SQL query.

Comment: To prevent surprises from future mysql version, you could get used to quote all your column names (not only the ones that might be a reserved name like "type") for a uniform look.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal that wasn't the problem as using a backtick around the `key` keyword has fixed it. If it really was line 1 then I have no idea how I could have set the `$con` variable.

Comment: @jordanmoore: Huh? I know what the problem was as I wrote the accepted answer. I'm talking about your assertion that "it says line 1, that's just because of how it's been executed, it's actually line 280". That's a MySQL error, so it's talking about line 1 of the input that you give to MySQL -- which is only one line long anyway. MySQL has no knowledge of the original PHP context.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal ah I'm sorry - I didn't check the name of the answer I accepted :oops: I didn't understand your comment correctly I feel, you meant that it was infact line 1 not line 240, and I thought you thought it was the first line of PHP. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you couldn't have looked this up yourself, but, [**yes**, `key` is a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

You should use backticks with your field names to avoid ever having to worry about this.

```
SELECT `bandHash`, `userHash`, `userPassHash`, `type`
  FROM `account_active`
 WHERE `key` = ?
```

This not only solves your problem, but it feels more explicit and (as you can see) aids syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [key is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

I'd consider renaming it to avoid using the quoted name everywhere

```
`key`
```